# How to delete an object in the heap that isn't stored to a variable pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I just found out that you can do this in C++:

```
class Line
{
public:
    Line(int x) : _length(x) {}
    int GetLength() { return _length; }
private:
    int _length;
};

int main()
{
    Line* line = new Line(3); // instead of doing this
    std::cout << line->GetLength();

    std::cout << (new Line(5))->GetLength(); // you can instantiate the object directly without storing it in a pointer
}
```

Now my question is, after that last line of code, does the object with length=5 get deleted immediately in the heap? If not, how do we delete it since we can't use

```
delete line;
```

like in the first object with length=3.

Comment: You've learned how to leak memory

Comment: Avoid using `new` directly and it becomes considerably harder to accidentally do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object doesn't get deleted: there is no corresponding call to `delete` for the call to `new` it was allocated with. Do assign it to a pointe then delete that and avoid a memory leak.

Better alternatives:

- just use the stack: `Line(5).GetLength()` will call Line's destructor and free any memory allocated (on the stack) automatically after that line since the temporary unnamed object goes out of scope.
- use `std::make_unique<Line>(5)->GetLength()`. Under the hood this does allocate a `new` Line on the heap. Aterwards, same story: when the unique_ptr this creates goes out of scope it's destructor is called and that will in turn call the corresponding `delete`.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I think I'll learn smart pointers for now. But using the stack somehow confuses me. Normally, if it goes out of scope, the object in the stack automatically gets deleted right? So how come I can still access it by reference like so:
`for(...) { Line line(3); Line* p = &line; }`
`std::cout << p->GetLength(); //still outputs 3!`

Comment: That shouldn't compile since p won't be defined outside of the loop. Even then, it is undefined behavior to access p as it would point to an object which went out of scope. 'undefined behavior' can be anything, including accidentally giving the 'expected' result. Likely because the memory where that line resided is still on the stack.

Comment: Oops, sorry mate. It was supposed to be like this: `Line* p; for(...) { Line line(3); p = &line; } std::cout << p->GetLength();` This compiles just fine and outputs 3.

Comment: Yeah for the reasons I mentioned. Likely if you'd add more unrelatd statements befor the call to p->GetLength() it will not output 3 anymore becasue the other statements used that part of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulation on discovering the concept of a "memory leak".

The next step on your adventure is to learn all about [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), and [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which will allow you to do pretty much the same thing, but without leaking memory all over the place.

And, as an extra bonus, you don't have to worry about `delete`ing anything, ever again.